# How to make a Jbutton show a menuitem list?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, jmenubar

Is there a way to show a menu item list when you click on a Jbutton? For example if I click on the Jbutton labelled `wrench`, it would show a menu item list with 2 options, like [this example](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/JavaImages/JMenuItemKeyStroke.PNG). Here's my code (the text emphasised with `**` is the button I want to show a menu item list when clicked on):

```
appletFrame = new JFrame(Settings.serverName);
        Loader.webclient = false;
        appletFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        appletFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
        JPanel appletPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout()); 
        appletFrame.setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(this.getClass().getResource("/resources/icon.png")));
        appletPanel.add(this);
        appletPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(767, 655));
        appletFrame.getContentPane().add(appletPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        appletFrame.pack();
        appletFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        appletFrame.setVisible(true);
        JMenuBar jmenubar = new JMenuBar();
        appletPanel.add(jmenubar, BorderLayout.PAGE_START); 
        layout = new FlowLayout();
        **ImageIcon wrench = new ImageIcon(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(this.getClass().getResource("/resources/wrench.png")));**
        ImageIcon key = new ImageIcon(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(this.getClass().getResource("/resources/key.png")));
        JButton button1 = new JButton("Vote");
        JButton button2 = new JButton("Item List");
        JButton button3 = new JButton("Screenshot");
        **JButton button4 = new JButton(wrench);**
        JButton button5 = new JButton(key);
        **button4.setBorder(null);
        **button4.setBorderPainted(false);**
        **button4.setContentAreaFilled(false);**
        button5.setBorder(null);
        button5.setBorderPainted(false);
        button5.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        jmenubar.setLayout(layout);
        jmenubar.add(button1);
        jmenubar.add(button2);
        jmenubar.add(button3);
        **jmenubar.add(button4);**
        jmenubar.add(button5);
        button1.addActionListener(this);
        button2.addActionListener(this);
        button3.addActionListener(this);
        **button4.addActionListener(this);**
        button5.addActionListener(this);
```

Comment: [*How to Use Combo Boxes*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html)?

Comment: [*How to Use (Sub)Menus*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html)?

Comment: @trashgod  I suspect the first is closer to what the OP wants, while the 2nd is a valid (in some cases better) alternative.

Comment: [*How to Use Tool Bars*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toolbar.html)?

Comment: Something like this : http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/JavaImages/JMenuItemKeyStroke.PNG

Answer (score 0):

Are you needing a SplitButton? Then there're some implemented package (include the Netbeans UI Components), you may love them.

If you need a tiny package for that, please have a look at following link:
http://code.google.com/p/jsplitbutton/